# Looking to use a users current logon credentials for Security

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

Using Abp Framework 3.4.0. Build a Web Application that lives inside a protected network so we want to use integrated security.  Active Directory is not used as they have single sign on system.

Where would be the best place to get the users Windows Login name and use it to check for Roles?  The Roles would be set up as part of the network single sign on system.

I'm guessing I should stick the windows login name into the ApbSession object at some point?

Thanks

Comment: Where? Read the docs on [External Authentication](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management#external-authentication). How to get the user's Windows Login name? That's unrelated to ABP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable Windows Authentication and then try `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`.

**launchSettings.json**

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55962/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
}
```

Reference: [How to enable Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

This [link](http://mikko.repolainen.fi/documents/aspdotnet-core-windows-authentication) is also very useful.